# jaccard (or any similarity) index on rows of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, similarity

I hope you can help me in a problem I am crashing my mind on.

I have a data.frame with three columns: `appl`, `cod`, `ipc`.
This dataset have multiple rows with the same `appl`, each rows corresponding to one `cod` which is associated to one `ipc`. The latter may be a list of one or more values. `appl` and `cod` are integer values.
An example

```
row    appl   cod         ipc

11  |  1206 | 3857183   | 16
12  |  1220 | 1063002   | 29
13  |  1299 | 46437     | c("26", "31", "33")
14  |  1317 | 685895    | c("10", "13", "14", "16")
15  |  1317 | 790606    | c("10", "13", "14", "16")
```

I need a number which tells me, for each value of `appl`, how similar is the composition of the list in `ipc`.
I have found the Jaccard index as a suitable mathematical index, but is applies only to couple of sets. I thought to compute the Jaccard index for each unique pair of `ipc` for each `appl` value, then computing the average.

I found the `set_similarity` function for the Jaccard index computation between two sets.

However, I do not know how to practically implement this strategy - or any other.

How do I implement correctly something like

```
for (each `appl`) 
{ put all `ipc` in a list, 
 take all possible unique combinations, 
 apply `set_similarity` on them,
 take the average }
```

?

I checked many times already answered questions about the topic but I cannot apply them successfully.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a simple jaccard use count(intersection of the two ipc sets = common elements) and divide it by count(union of the two sets = all elements of both ipc sets)

This gives a local solution which means measures similarity between the two given sets. But if you want to compute a global solution that you can compare every one apple with another one in a global space, then you should first gather all possible ipc codes for each subject(e.g. apple) and then use it as the denominator of above jaccard calculation.

A more complex scenario with frequencies on each item also can be solved by considering each ipc as a histogram and then computing the histogram distance by one of the different functions (Earth Mover Distance OR Jensen-Shannon entropy distance etc.)

To do so assume both ipc collections are sets of similar items with a 0 frequency on each non existing item on either of sets